# How to remove last characters for some but not all columns of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to format multiple columns in a pd dataframe by removing the the last six characters and making all lines proper case. I know how to do it on a single column but can't figure out a clean way of doing it in multiple columns without coding one line for each column. Note these are only 4 of the 20 columns in the dataframe.

| QA Support | UA Support | Dev Support | Prod Support |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Stephen Andrews AB1603 | Scott Barker AB2044 | Edward Boyes AB1548 | David Nesmith AB1996 |
| Ruth Xavier AB1594 | LENA Kelly AB1708 | Angela NEVIN AB1242 | Renee ALLEN AB2162 |
| Ryan Trussell AB3102 | Roland Irons AB1772 | Aaron Nixon AB1249 | George Folkes AB3400 |

```
   df['QA Support'] = df['QA Support'].str[:-6].str.title()
   df['UA Support'] = df['UA Support'].str[:-6].str.title()
   df['Dev Support'] = df['Dev Support'].str[:-6].str.title()
   df['Prod Support'] = df['Prod Support'].str[:-6].str.title()
```

How can I make the change to multiple columns in a single line of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dataframes do not have the `str` methods, only series, so you cannot apply them to a dataframe (or subset of columns) all at once. However, you can `stack` the columns into a single series with multi-index, transform them and `unstack` them.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"QA Support": ["Stephen Andrews AB1603", "Ruth Xavier AB1594", "Ryan Trussell AB3102"], "UA Support": ["Scott Barker AB2044", "LENA Kelly AB1708","Roland Irons AB1772"]})
columns = ["QA Support", "UA Support"]
df[columns] = df[columns].stack().str[:-6].str.title().unstack()
```

Alternatively, use `apply` to apply the same function to several columns.

```
df[columns] = df[columns].apply(lambda s: s.str[:-6].str.title())
```

Finally, you could just use a conventional `for` loop:

```
for column in ["QA Support", "UA Support"]:
    df[column] = df[column].str[:-6].str.title()
```

Comment: The third option did the trick. I can't use the first because the count of employees is big (I only have a subset) and it changes regularly.  I am not sure I understand the second option, what does the "lambda" command means? How does it know which columns to apply? Anyway, as I mentioned above, the third one worked fine.

Comment: Not sure I understand why the first two options wouldn't work. You just need to set the`columns` variable to contain the names of the columns you need to change.